# Exception while adding data to to the database -overflow error converting int to data type numeric

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm getting an exception for some data sets when I add them to the table. Data is coming from a WEB API and there are no exceptions for the following data columns.

```
"RRP": 2.98074513,
"Cost": 2.533633360
```

But when it is trying to add the following data sets it shows an SQL Exception

```
"RRP": 2.92,
"Cost": 2.4820
```

and this -

```
"RRP": 4.90,
"Cost": 4.1650
```

The exception is "Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider, MessageArithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric"

SQL Table structure -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DailyConsumptionLogs](
    [UsageLineId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ResourceId] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [RRP] [numeric](15, 13) NOT NULL,
    [Cost] [numeric](15, 13) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Insert statement executed in C# -

```
string sql_command = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO DailyConsumptionLogs(
                                                        ResourceId,
                                                        RRP,
                                                        Cost) 
                                  VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')",
                                               item.ResourceId,
                                               item.RRP,
                                               item.Cost);
```

Comment: You need to show your `insert` statement.  Based on your values, there is no conversion going on from `int` to `numeric`.  The problem might lie in a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated the question with an insert statement. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is the command taken after using a breakpoint -

Correct command

```
  INSERT INTO DailyConsumptionLogs(ResourceId,RRP,Cost)VALUES('03E2F28B',2.98074513,2.53363336)
```

Exception Command

```
INSERT INTO DailyConsumptionLogs (ResourceId,RRP,Cost)v VALUES ('03E2F28B',4.9,4.165)
```

2. Both are defined as `numeric(15, 13)` data type
3. Yes insert it directly to the DB gets the following exception in SQL server

*Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.*

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you share the value of the sql_command after the execution of
   the assignment line? Both correct and incorrect.
2. How are item.RRP, item.Cost defined?
3. Do you have any exception inserting directly to the DB?

   INSERT INTO DailyConsumptionLogs(ResourceId, RRP, Cost) VALUES (1,4.90,4.1650)
   INSERT INTO DailyConsumptionLogs(ResourceId, RRP, Cost) VALUES (1,'2.92', '2.4820')